# Heir Class Constructor Throws CS7036 "No Argument Given" Exception

Tags: c#, inheritance, exceptions

I'm trying to create a class that holds the data for an an attack, called `Attack`. I also have special attacks that have more properties, and so I wanted to create a different class that inherits all of the properties of `Attack` while adding some more, so I created a class called `Special` that inherits `Attack`.

This is what my class structure looks like:

```
public class Attack
{
    public Attack()
    {

    }

    public class Special : Attack
    {
        public Special()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My compiler is okay with this. However, as soon as I try adding arguments to the constructor of the `Attack` class, for example...

```
public class Attack
{
    public Attack(float damage, float staminaCost)
    {

    }

    public class Special : Attack
    {
        public Special()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My compiler throws an error:

```
Line 13: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'damage' of 'Attack.Attack(float, float)'
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I'm not calling `Attack(float damage, float staminaCost)`, so why is it giving me grief over arguments? I tried un-nesting the classes but it doesn't make a difference. I need the constructor for `Attack.Special` to take in different arguments. Can someone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when `new SpecialAttack()` is called, before the `SpecialAttack()` constructor is hit, parent constructors are hit.

The language lets you omit/ignore typing the explicit call to the constructor, but that's only for no-arg `()` constructors.

Behind the scenes, the structure in the first example looks more like

```cs
public class Attack
{
    public Attack()
    {

    }

    public class Special : Attack
    {
        public Special() : base()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If the parent only has one constructor, and that constructor has arguments, you have to tell the compiler how to invoke the parent constructor. Thankfully it's pretty easy regardless.

```cs
public class Attack
{
    public Attack(float damage, float staminaCost)
    {

    }

    public class Special : Attack
    {
        public Special(): base(0, 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I should add for clarification that I do need my constructor for `Attack.Special` to take in different arguments than the constructor for `Attack`. Is this solution going to allow me to do this, or will it make the constructor for `Attack.Special` become the same as that of `Attack`?

Comment: Reading your explanation made me realize that a better solution would be to give `Attack` a parameterless constructor. Not only would it allow me to omit explicitly calling the parent constructor, I also plan to use XML serialization, and classes serialized with XML must have an explicit parameterless constructor. Thanks for the info!

Comment: As i consider it more, I wonder if I will need to explicitly define a paramterless constructor for `Attack.Special` as well, since I plan to serialize those objects as well. Would you happen to know this?